# `NoClassDefFoundError` in Artifact built with IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, jvm, sbt

I use Intellij Idea 2017.3 (Ultimate Edition) to build an artifact (an executable Jar) from a Scala/SBT project; Scala version is 2.12.
Since I have added a dependency to [Scallop](https://github.com/scallop/scallop) recently, I can no longer execute the Jar file because the Scallop class `ScallopConf` is not in the Jar file:

```
$ java -jar executable.jar 
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rogach/scallop/ScallopConf
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.rogach.scallop.ScallopConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
```

I can confirm that the `ScallopConf` class is not packaged into the Jar file by inspecting it manually. All other dependencies are there, no matter if they were added initially or later.

This is how I added the dependency to the `build.sbt` file in the project root directory:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.rogach" %% "scallop" % "3.1.1"
```

The project compiles fine both within the IDE and with `sbt compile`. I can also run it fine within the IDE.

I created the artifact within the IDE in a standard way. Is there anything particular I need to pay attention to, possibly related to Scallop?

Comment: Check in the [artifact settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#artifact_configs) that this library is actually gets packed into the jar. Do you see it there?

Comment: @andrey no, it's not listed there. All the other dependencies were added automatically as in `Extracted 'scala-reflect.jar'` etc. After selecting it in the list of available elements with `Extract into Output Root`, the Jar is runnable, thanks! Question is: why do I need to do this manually for this one?

Comment: On SBT projects the artifact configuration is not auto-synched with build.sbt file (related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9955 ) as it is now with Gradle or Maven. The IDE automatically adds all the dependencies at the moment when you create the artifact. After you have modified the dependencies configuration, the artifact settings should be manually adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Andrey , the artifact settings are not automatically updated when the SBT dependencies change. To make sure everything is up-to-date, the workaround is hence to re-create the artifact after updating the SBT dependencies.

So this issue is not related to the specific dependency (Scallop in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Conflicts are happening between class files of jars, therefore in the above example when libraries are removed from <kbd>File</kbd> | <kbd>Project Structure</kbd>  |  <kbd>Artifacts</kbd>  |  <kbd>Output Layout</kbd> . Everything runs fine.

In my case I had dependencies on other jars as well, so when I did this activity of removing all other libraries. `ClassNotFoundException` was gone but `NoClassFoundEx` is coming for dependent libraries which I removed.

In order to get to the exact solution I am forced to evaluate all the jar files one by one and removed unwanted libraries to get to the exact solution.